# Create instances of child classes with @inject annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have concerned with DI using Google guice as following
I have class B, and its children classes B1, B2. All classes use default constructor.

Then I create a bind class as:

```
public Binding extends AbstractModule{
   bind(B1.class);
   bind(B2.class);
}
```

And the application class I declare:

```
public Application{
   @Inject
   B1 b1;

   @Inject
   B2 b2;
}
```

I can directly use b1 and b2 instance without call new B1() or new B2().

Now, I add a constructor without parameter inside class B:

```
public B {
  public B(){}
}
```

Then I cannot use b1, b2 instance anymore, they are null.

My questions are:

1. What should I have to edit to continue b1, b2 without call "new" or call Injector instance?
2. If 1 is impossible, what is the properly solution to create instance of so many child classes B1, B2..., B10?

Comment: what is the error are you facing, after adding constructor?

Comment: @AmidalaSivaKumar b1, b2 become null. Thus, NPE occurs when using them.

Comment: Though if you do not provide constructor like `public B(){}`, JVM implicitly adds one default constructor. I do not see any wrong with it and cause issue

Comment: @AmidalaSivaKumar me too. However, I thought there is something wrong with google guice for this case.